# Iterate through a file reading first N values

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, loops, iteration

I am reading 3 lines at a time from a file which has numbers 1,2,3...100

I want the output to look something like this
1
2
3
2
3
4
3
4
5

However with the following code, it is printing continuous numbers

```
with open("/home/osboxes/num", "r+") as f:
for line in f:
    print(line)
    line2 = f.__next__()
    print(line2)
    line3 = f.__next__()
    print(line3)
```

Is there a way to go back to the iteration and skip the file line and display the output as shown above

Comment: Have you tried `seek()` method?

Comment: If you wanna print repeated numbers you have you repeat them. What are you do in is just calling the `next` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that instead of your file object we have an iterator like `iter(range(100))` in order to produce our expected result using `next` you can copy the iterator using `itertools.tee` as many times as you want and create a `zip` from your iterators based on your expected output:

```
In [3]: r = iter(range(100))

In [4]: from itertools import tee

In [5]: r, n, m = tee(r, 3)  # copy the iterator 3 times 

In [6]: next(n)  # consume the first item of n
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: next(m);next(m)  # consume the first 2 items of m
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: list(zip(r, n, m))

#Out[8]: 
#[(0, 1, 2),
# (1, 2, 3),
# (2, 3, 4),
# (3, 4, 5),
# (4, 5, 6),
# (5, 6, 7),
# ...
```

Now you can do the same thing with file object:

```
from itertools import tee

with open("/home/osboxes/num", "r+") as f:
    f, n, m = tee(f, 3)
    next(n);next(m);next(m)
    for i, j , k in zip(r, n, m):
        print(i, j, k)  # or do something else with i,j,k
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a smaller file as you mentioned, then you can use following code, but if it's much bigger than prefer using `seek()` method:

```
with open("abc.txt", "r+") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in range(2, len(data)):
        print("%s %s %s" % (data[i-2].rstrip(), data[i-1].rstrip(), data[i].rstrip()), end = " ")
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

If storing the whole file in a variable isn't a problem, an easy solution would be:

```
with open("num", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for i in range(len(lines) - 2):
        print(lines[i])
        print(lines[i + 1])
        print(lines[i + 2])
```

For a more efficient solution, see @Kasramvd solution using iterators.

As an alternative without iterators, you can store the last 2 values:

```
with open("num", "r+") as f:
    prev1, prev2 = None, None
    for line in f:
        if prev1 is not None and prev2 is not None:
            print(prev1)
            print(prev2)
            print(line)
        prev1, prev2 = prev2, line
```

Comment: Sometimes, performance is less important that code maintainability (I like your solution but developers will spend more time to understand it). As I said, that depends on the input size.

Comment: *Sometimes, performance is less important that code maintainability*: correct and seems obvious ;). *developers will spend more time to understand it*: Nope! it one knows the concept of iterator they will easily understand the `zip`/`tee` solution otherwise the shouldn't use file object and `open` function at the first place.

Comment: _otherwise the shouldn't use file object and open function at the first place._ The problem is when someone else (less experienced with iterators in Python for instance) has to read that code.